# Data migration from Sybase to Teradata

Tags: sybase, teradata, sap-ase, data-migration

I am trying to do a case study on migrating our data from Sybase to Teradata. We would than try to implement the same in our organization. Based on my study what I know is Teradata is excellent when it comes down to allowing maximum number of concurrent queries, more number of active sessions per system, maximum number of transactions including ETL jobs etc. But are there any other added advantages we can get (where Sybase lacks) by moving to Teradata? Also what all key factors or constraints I should consider while performing such migration?

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges.  Teradata is an OLAP solution, Sybase ASE is an OLTP solution.  Writes are going to be significantly faster on ASE, reads are going to be faster on Teradata.  Key factors to consider would be the business use case for the data.  If it's an supporting operations, then you would be better off keeping your ASE, and then augmenting it with Teradata as your DW for reporting and analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Michael, Sybase IQ can be compared to TD as an OLAP solution.

To OP: Cost comparison would be a huge advantage to Sybase. Also, you can maintain Syb yourself, whilst for TD you're likely to contract TD staff to maintain the hardware.

But no matter the size, you can bring Teradata to its knees just as easy with quite a few concurrent queries or poorly written ETLs. Teradata performs very well though on heavy aggregation of huge dimensions, if skewed well across controllers.

Comment: The question is tagged Sybase-ASE, which is why I commented. IQ is definitely an OLAP solution, but not relevant to the question.